# How do I install cuda for Ubuntu studio 21.04?

Tags: nvidia, cuda, 21.04, ubuntu-studio

- OS: Ubuntu studio 21.04.
- GPU: GeForce GTX 980

It's an operating system that has pre-installed software like the animation software called blender.
I downloaded the operating system here: https://ubuntustudio.org/

But when I try running blender, it tells me I can't use the graphics card because of a Cuda software issue so it will use the CPU instead. My graphics card is a GeForce GTX 980 and I know that it's compatible with Cuda by running the command

**lspci | grep -i nvidia**

After I ran that command, I get: **2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980] (rev a1)**
So I'm assuming that means it should work because it has the word *compatible* in the sentence.

When I go to the [cuda website](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#verify-that-gcc-is-installed) it says that the latest supported ubuntu version is
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, not the 21.04 version I have.

The [tutorial](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2021/04/08/step-by-step-cuda-ubuntu-21-04-installation-guide/) I found online didn't work for me.

I also tried [this](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/21.04/ubuntu-multiverse-amd64/nvidia-cuda-toolkit_11.2.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html)
But the terminal says **The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libcuinj64-11.2
Recommends: libnvcuvid1 but it is not installable**

Does anyone have a working method of installing Cuda on Ubuntu studio 21.04?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue by learning from [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-21-04) tutorial.

The commands I used were:

- sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
- sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
- sudo reboot

---

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Now my graphics card works with blender.

I think the issue was:
that the nvidia driver version that was auto installed was the wrong one. I remember seeing the phrase "unmet dependencies" and nvidia 460 the first round I tried installing cuda but didnt think nothing of it.
But in the new install method, I looked up possible nvidia driver installations with the command **ubuntu-drivers devices** that listed a reccomended nvidia 470 driver. At first I tried doing that with the command **sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470** then trying to re-install cuda with the **sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit** command but it didnt work. Only When I installed the older version of nivida with the **sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460** command did it work.